# Can I add my keyboard layout to next Ubuntu version?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I want to know how to add Arabic (Tunisia) and French (Tunisia) to next Ubuntu version.

Because, there is file named 'ma' with all Moroccan keyboard layouts added to Ubuntu automatically. And I want to make the same thing with Tunisian keyboard layouts.

Thank You.

Comment: http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/462 indicates that Tunisia uses the same layout as Morocco. Are you sure that "Arabic (Morocco)" won't work for you?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, I'm sure, we have (in Tunisia) two additional letters. and that's why we need an Arabic (Tunisia) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need to submit a bug report. So, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. In the input box type

```
ubuntu-bug xkeyboard-config
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The apport program will begin to collect information about your system, and the page for the bug report will be opened in your default web browser. Just fill in the blanks and read the instructions.

Comment: Since the question is about keyboard layouts, I think the package should be xkeyboard-config rather than langpack-locales.

Comment: Yes, I got confused :)

Comment: Thank you, do you have any article or video explaining that. I understood it, but I want to know more about that.

Comment: @GeekEmad: This is an example bug report with a fix re adding additional Bangla layouts: https://launchpad.net/bugs/793778 In this case I suppose that a new file should be created in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` rather than editing an existing one.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thank you, and yes I made a new file with 3 keyboard layouts called 'tn'.

Comment: @GeekEmad: Great. Hope you are able to prepare a patch based on it. Don't hesitate to ask for help would you have further questions.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson what do you mean with "patch based on it" ?

Comment: @GeekEmad: I mean a proposal to modify the xkeyboard-config package in the form of a patch (or merge proposal).

Comment: I've a question, I'm sure you've its answer, How can I submit a new file for usr/share/i18n/locals (regional format)?

Comment: @GeekEmad I don't think you need to write a patch. It might speed up the process, but if Arabic/French (Tunisia) is well-known then the developers should know what to do (and you can submit a new bug report if you are not satisfied with the result).

Comment: @edwin no, it's not known, it's know only in Wikipedia! (they talk about additional letters in Arabic (Tunisia)). Also, I didn't talk about the third layout and it's for "Standard Tunisian" (a language under development).. (it has a Lain alphabet, a dictionary and even grammar, but it's not announced yet)

Comment: I don't know why firefox spell checker for example, ubuntu and many other 'things' doesn't support the ISO 3 ? .. because when I write 'aeb' ubuntu/firefox didn't read it as 'Tunisian Arabic'.. do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly add the layout to the distribution release, you'd need to ask the devs for that. If you are talking about adding it to a disk yoursbeslf, the absolute easiest thing to do is just install it normally

Comment: and how can I contact Ubuntu devs?!

Comment: @GeekEmad: You do that by filing a bug. ;)